# Unable to access “44 GB Volume” Error mounting /dev/sda2

Tags: ntfs

I have a Compaq laptop which received a bump yesterday. After that, the system doesn't load the Windows 7, I get the blue screen error each time I try to load.

I also have Ubuntu 13.04 installed on the system, through which I can access all my drives except the C: drive(which is so called in windows)

I have some important files in that drive can somebody suggest me how to retrieve them?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If it's a hardware error and the data is important to you, then you should stop using it immediately and send it to a company that specializes in harddisk recovery. The more you use it, the more you increase the chance that it won't be possible to retrieve information from it.

If you really want to try it yourself, I would suggest that you try `ddresque`. This will read and re-read your disk, trying to copy as much data as possible from it to a file. It may be that this is enough to get a perfect copy, but if it doesn't, ibas.no has a good tool for recovering files from damaged disks/file systems.

Before you try using `ddresque`, you should read its manual: http://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/manual/ddrescue_manual.html